# I want to share a hard drive with password on Windows XP Pro

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, software-rec, network-shares

I want share a hard drive with password so that if anyone wants to access the drive it should prompt for password.

I need configuration steps on the computer where the drive is located and if required the settings on the shared computer. The operating system is Windows XP Professional

Answer (score 0):

its possible (but not recommended) to share the root of the drive with standard windows file sharing - you'd get the same effect using a folder, unless its impossible to move the files .

I'd suggest creating a new user account for the file share (and use these to access the file) and disallowing anonymous access - you can do this through the advanced sharing button when you set up the share

Answer (score 0):

If basic file sharing is turned on, your drive is *already* shared.  Just go to any computer on the same network and enter `\\computername\c$`.  It will prompt for a password, just like you asked.  Any account on the machine in the administrator's group will work.

Comment: this commands are to be typed on command prompt,what would b the computer name,is there any value in place of c

Comment: You didn't say so in your original question. Most people use the GUI. You can check the computer name on the server with whoami - which will give computername/account